# Markdown quirkiness with hyperlinks including images

Tags: bug, status-declined, markdown, editor

I noticed some weird behavior of Markdown regarding adding hyperlinks to images.

Start with an image:

```
![alt text][1]


  [1]: http://example.com/image.jpg
```

Now, highlight `![alt text][1]` and hit Ctrl+L (add a hyperlink).  instead of the expected prompt for hyperlink URL, you just get:

```
alt text
```

In other words, the reference to the image URL is gone entirely!

---

Now, let's say you manually entered that link, then added another paragraph:

```
[![alt text][1]][2]

second paragraph

  [1]: http://example.com/image.jpg
  [2]: http://example.com/page1.html
```

Now you want "second paragraph" to be a link, so you highlight it, hit Ctrl+L, and enter `http://example.com/page2.html` as the URL and hit OK.  You get this:

```
[![alt text][1]][1]

[second paragraph][2]


  [1]: http://example.com/page1.html
  [2]: http://example.com/page2.html
```

Notice that the URL to the image has been completely removed!

Comment: I think you mean http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56460/markdown-cannot-parse-posts-with-added-links-when-there-are-images-with-links-in

Comment: @balpha you're right, i had too many tabs open and copied the wrong url

Comment: Part 2 of this is a dup of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56460/markdown-cannot-parse-posts-with-added-links-when-there-are-images-with-links-in, which is now [status-completed]

Comment: You know it's over when Atwood adds the status tag.

Answer (score -1):

Er.. what? You want an image src = an HTML page?

Images as links work fine..

#### Markup

```
[![alt text][1]][2]

second paragraph

  [1]: https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-logo.png
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com
```

#### Output

[image]

second paragraph

Comment: He's right though, it doesn't work with the WMD buttons or the keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: it's open source. You want it that bad, go for it.. http://code.google.com/p/wmd-new/

Comment: i thought i explained it in a pretty clear step-by-step manner. there were two things.  First: You have a post with an image. I want to make the image a clickable link. it doesn't work (with shortcut or toolbar button).  Second: assuming you managed to manually create the image with hyperlink above it. if try to add another regular link in the next paragraph using the keyboard shortcut or toolbar, the reference to the image is deleted, and now you have img src=html page, which is **not** what should be there.