# Markdown cannot parse posts with added links when there are Images with Links in them

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, editor

In this Meta question, I posted a image, and a link, I've enclosed the markdown text:

```
I was reading [a recent Meta question about users not showing up on the Area 51 Stack Exchange 'users' page][1] (the one that has to do with the Beta. Like the Gaming Beta User's page).  I was [paging through the beta users][2], and after the 8th or so page, was given the following error message:

It appears that since you guys use user flair, and the flair is rate limited, anyone who tries to view more than a few pages of users on the Beta page will be IP Banned for a specific amount of time. 

[![alt text][3]][4]


  [1]: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56447/why-arent-some-users-listed-as-participating-in-the-beta-on-area-51
  [2]: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1338?page=23&phase=beta&users=reputation#tab-top
  [3]: http://lh5.ggpht.com/_MJ7SHaJorfU/TDdRcbosK2I/AAAAAAAAApA/OhazJLtlVCg/s800/Banned.jpg
  [4]: http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/2__Wdst_ielNS9LXqR8DAQ?feat=directlink
```

You can reproduce this issue by creating an image with a link:

```
[![alt text][3]][4]
```

And then inserting a link **before** that image.  Every link you insert before that overwrites the image url, resulting in a lost image.

Comment: This is probably because it searches for "[xyz][n]" and ignores "xyz" instead of recursively parsing it. +1, though, because this is annoying editor behaviour.

Comment: +1: I saw this as well.  Nice to know I can probably work around it by adding links after the image and then moving by cut-paste (I'll verify that works at some point).  I worked around it by manual markdown edits...

Comment: sweet. I reported this a year ago and Jeff didn't read the whole question, then when I explained further his response was "WMD is open source, go fix it yourself". http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28029/markdown-quirkiness-with-hyperlinks-including-images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the editor was indeed ignoring the nested references when renumbering the link definitions. This will be fixed in the next build.

Note that this only works *one* level deep of nesting – the only use case for nested references is a linked image; anything else doesn't make sense.